Destroying an object during construction properly
Alright, let us assume this example:
class MyClass
{
private:
    unsigned int Counter;
    const string Pins;

    AnotherClass AnotherObject;


public:
MyClass(const string FileName1, const string FileName2)
    : Pins("D00_LSB,D01,D02,D03"), AnotherObject("pAll_Pins")
{

if ( SomeCondition ) {
 cout << "Aborting construction of Object" << endl;
 return;
}

}

What I need is for the constructor to be terminated, if a condition is met, in such a way that it will also delete the object and whatever exists inside of it (the AnotherObject as well). What is the proper way of doing that? I have read that just calling the destructor for the object itself doesn't always behave properly, depending on how the object got created.
The system where this needs to run is using C++15. I haven't really tried any different outcomes. I am currently just doing research about what would be the optimal way of doing things.

You are supposed to throw an exception. Then everything will work correctly automatically. Manually calling destructors is simply wrong and causing undefined behavior.

As far as C++ is concerned, if your constructor returns without throwing an exception then your object was successfully constructed, and its destructor will be called at the end of its lifetime (when it goes out of scope if it has automatic lifetime or when it is deleted if it has dynamic lifetime).

I am not avoiding exceptions. I just didn't know they can abort the construction of an object. Can you show me an example of how to handle this with an exception?

@Carrot13 Can you show me an example of how to handle this with an exception? -- Just change the example you posted into one that calls throw instead of return.

Such an example is shown in the linked duplicate, above.

Appreciate it, thanks :)

Either throw an exception or use 2-phase construction so the 2nd phase can return a failure code.

Re: "will also delete the object" -- you can only delete what you newed; that's not the constructor's job. What you're after is destroying the parts that have been construct4ed, and that's the compiler's job when the constructor throws an exception.

Side note: There are a few cases where you do manually destroy an object, but these are not needed here and rare in general. When you have a few minutes, see placement new for details so that you have this tool in your toolbox should you run into a case where you need it.
